# nodeJs , run sql twice can combine them to json

Tags: javascript, sql, json, node.js

I am building the api by using node js.
here is my code

```
var keyword = req.body.keyword;
var sql = "SELECT xxxx WHERE xxx";
  connection.query(sql,function (err,row){
   if(err) {
    res.json({"Error" : true});
   } else {
    res.json({"Result" : row});
    }
  });
```

Then , I got the result

```
{
  "Result": [
    {
  "xxx": xxx,
  "yyy": "yyyy"
  }
 ]
}
```

But now , I need to combine many sql result in to one json .

```
{"ResultA":[{"xxx","xxx" , "yyy":"yyyy"}] , 
"ResultB":[{"xxx","xxx" , "yyy":"yyyy"}] , 
"ResultC":[{"xxx","xxx" , "yyy":"yyyy"}]  }
```

Can I store the result in variable of sql then run :

```
res.json({"ResultA" : a , "ResultB" :b , "ResultC":c});
```

to get the result ?

I tried to copy the code and add

```
res.write(",");
```

to link the jsons , but It tell me i cannot write after end.

Comment: Assuming you are using node-mysql, take a look at this: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#multiple-statement-queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to collect your entire response first before sending it back to the client. This means buffering your output of each query. For example:

```
var results = [];
connection.query('SELECT xxx FROM yyyy', function(err, row) {
  if (err)
    result.push({ErrorA: true});
  else
    result.push({ResultA: row});
  onFinish();
});
connection.query('SELECT xxx FROM yyyy', function(err, row) {
  if (err)
    result.push({ErrorB: true});
  else
    result.push({ResultB: row});
  onFinish();
});
connection.query('SELECT xxx FROM yyyy', function(err, row) {
  if (err)
    result.push({ErrorC: true});
  else
    result.push({ResultC: row});
  onFinish();
});
function onFinish() {
  if (results.length === 3)
    res.json(results);
}
```

You could simplify this if you don't need to use query-specific result key names (e.g. `ResultA`, `ResultB`, etc.) and result order doesn't matter:

```
var results = [];
var queries = [
  'SELECT xxxx FROM yyyy',
  'SELECT xxxx FROM yyyy',
  'SELECT xxxx FROM yyyy'
];
for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; ++i)
  connection.query(queries[i], onResult);
function onResult(err, row) {
  if (err)
    results.push({Error: true});
  else
    results.push({Result: row});
  if (results.length === queries.length)
    res.json(results);
}
```